# How to add icon and change the app name in phone gap build application

Tags: phonegap-build

I have created a Jquery html5 mobile application and then I had created a apk using the phone gap site but when I install the application on the device I am not getting the app icon which
have added to the route directory and also want to know how to change the app name

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You also have to specify icon and splashscreen in your **config.xml**, add these 2 lines in config.xml and you will have icon and splash screen:

```
<icon src="icon.png" />
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
```

More detailed spec for icons and splashscreen for various platform are specified here: 
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/config_ref_images.md.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **config.xml** file for your project. Next, add `<icon src =" res / icon.png "/>` into config.xml.

Or `<icon src="res/ios/icon.png" platform="ios" width="57" height="57" density="mdpi" />` than more ( http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html )

Answer (score -1):

You just need to go to your `config.xml` that you can find it in this Path:

```
youAppName>config.xml
```

then put this line of code before the platform name:

```
<icon src="Path/PicName.png" />
```

Example:

```
<icon src="platforms/android/res/PicName.png" />
```